# how to download serverless.yml from exist lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm aws-lambda newbie.
I need to use npm to deploy on my local pc.
I already created lambda function and uploaded layers by using the console.

I need all of lambda files such as serverless.yml template file.... but I don't know how to download theses files from aws to local pc

please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try scp command for the same.

`scp -i /directory/to/abc.pem user@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:path/to/file /your/local/directory/files/to/download`

abc.pem is key for your computer.

you can try with the password as well.

`scp user@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:path/to/file /your/local/directory/files/to/download`

Comment: this gives not information at all about how to get the yaml file